# How do I get a HWND from inside a DLL?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, hwnd, directsound

I have a DLL that I want to play sounds using Direct Sound.  In order to play sounds, I need the HWND of the executable.  I don't have a HWND of the executable that loads the DLL.  How do I get that in the DLL without passing it in from the executable?

Comment: `HWND` of the executable? "HWND" stands for "Handle to Window"... did you mean `HMODULE`?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think he needs a HWND of a window within the process...  Direct Sound requires an HWND for initialization.

Comment: Could you just create your own (hidden) window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [GetCurrentProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the current process Id.

You could then call EnumWindows, and check each window with [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find a window associated with your process.

However, an easier option might be to just generate your own Window.  You can create a 1x1 pixel window that is not visible, and use it with Direct Sound.

This has the advantage of working even if your calling process doesn't have a usable window (or deletes window handles regularly).

Comment: I'm going to try to create a small window like you and shf301 suggested.

Comment: creating windows is of course very possible BUT it really should'nt be your first choice - windows are somewhat resource hungry, have their own needs and are generally targeted towards actual UI application with their own message loops (be it implicitly or explictly), thats a lot to consider and implement for a small DLL. Its usually much better to either pass an HWND reference to the DLL via DLL functions or grab some verifiable HWND from a running, controllable process - this process has to be monitored, of course ...

Comment: @specializt Don't always agree, though - if you're not certain how your DLL will be used, and want it to be general purpose, it's a safe option.  Relying on an HWND that could get destroyed has its own drawbacks.

Comment: generating windows inside of DLLs is _never_ "safe". At all. Its actually a security risk and stability issue since your DLL can be unloaded / destroyed without being notified, leaking whole windows and so on. Its what professionals call "bad code", mostly. If this were still 1990's such a DLL could easily crash the whole system because its being overloaded with memory leaks. Thank god its the 21s century.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`GetGUIThreadInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633506%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the main thread. This gets you a bunch of HWNDs. If you need a top-level HWND, pick any valid one (not all values may be filled) and find its top level ancestor with `GetAncestor(GA_ROOT)`.